# gradient descent using python numpy matrix class

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, regression

I'm trying to implement the univariate gradient descent algorithm in python. I have tried a bunch of different ways and nothing works. What follows is one example of what I've tried. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!!

```
from numpy import *

class LinearRegression:

  def __init__(self,data_file):
    self.raw_data_ref = data_file
    self.theta = matrix([[0],[0]])
    self.iterations = 1500
    self.alpha = 0.001


  def format_data(self):
    data = loadtxt(self.raw_data_ref, delimiter = ',')
    dataMatrix = matrix(data)
    x = dataMatrix[:,0]
    y = dataMatrix[:,1]
    m = y.shape[0]
    vec = mat(ones((m,1)))
    x = concatenate((vec,x),axis = 1)
    return [x, y, m]


  def computeCost(self, x, y, m):
    predictions = x*self.theta
    squaredErrorsMat = power((predictions-y),2)
    sse = squaredErrorsMat.sum(axis = 0)
    cost = sse/(2*m)
    return cost


  def descendGradient(self, x, y, m):
      for i in range(self.iterations):

          predictions = x*self.theta
          errors = predictions - y
          sumDeriv1 = (multiply(errors,x[:,0])).sum(axis = 0)
          sumDeriv2 = (multiply(errors,x[:,1])).sum(axis = 0)

          print self.computeCost(x,y,m)

          tempTheta = self.theta
          tempTheta[0] = self.theta[0] - self.alpha*(1/m)*sumDeriv1
          tempTheta[1] = self.theta[1] - self.alpha*(1/m)*sumDeriv2

          self.theta[0] = tempTheta[0]
          self.theta[1] = tempTheta[1]


      return self.theta



regressor = LinearRegression('ex1data1.txt')
output = regressor.format_data()
regressor.descendGradient(output[0],output[1],output[2])
print regressor.theta
```

A little update; I previously tried to do it in a more "vectorized" way, like so:

```
def descendGradient(self, x, y, m):
  for i in range(self.iterations):

      predictions = x*self.theta
      errors = predictions - y

      sumDeriv1 = (multiply(errors,x[:,0])).sum(axis = 0)
      sumDeriv2 = (multiply(errors,x[:,1])).sum(axis = 0)

      gammaMat = concatenate((sumDeriv1,sumDeriv2),axis = 0)
      coeff = self.alpha*(1.0/m)
      updateMatrix = gammaMat*coeff
      print updateMatrix, gammaMat


      jcost  = self.computeCost(x,y,m)
      print jcost
      tempTheta = self.theta
      tempTheta = self.theta - updateMatrix
      self.theta = tempTheta

  return self.theta
```

This resulted in a theta of [[-0.86221218],[ 0.88827876]].

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nothing works?"  What happens when you try to run this code?  What did you think was wrong, and what have you tried in order to fix the code?

Comment: @Colin, thanks a lot for responding. I don't know why it didn't work but the following occurred to me: extraneous temporary variable storing the value of theta, misplaced return statement, and as per below, not specifying floats. I also tried to implement it in a more "vectorized" way as well, as per my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems, both are related to floating points:

1. Initialize your theta matrix like this:

```
self.theta = matrix([[0.0],[0.0]])
```

2. Change the update lines, replacing `(1/m)` with `(1.0/m)`:

```
tempTheta[0] = self.theta[0] - self.alpha*(1.0/m)*sumDeriv1
tempTheta[1] = self.theta[1] - self.alpha*(1.0/m)*sumDeriv2
```

On an unrelated note: your `tempTheta` variable is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks jeremy for your tips. The extraneous tempTheta variable had crossed my mind but I wasn't sure about it. Also, using the decimals to tell python to use floats didn't change the outcome. I still haven't gotten it to work... but not for lack of trying. I think theta should converge to [[-3.63029144],[1.16636235]]. Thanks again.

Comment: Making the above changes and making `self.iterations = 15000` and making `self.alpha = 0.01` gave me a result of `[[-3.89578088]
 [ 1.19303364]]` (using the ex1data1.txt from the Coursera course).